# HERE maps audio prompts start before audio ducking

Tags: android, here-api

I'm testing the Android HERE maps premium SDK, and have the audio prompts working (including the voice TTS prompts), and have been adding support for audio focus and ducking (to lower the volume of any music that is playing).  This is described in the [HERE sdk docs for audio management](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/audio-management.html).  I'm familiar with these audio focus APIs and have implemented ducking on Android before.

However, with the HERE sdk I'm using the AudioFeedbackListener to trigger the ducking, but the TTS audio is out of sync with the audio focus; basically the ducking works, but it is delayed by about 0.25 to 0.5 seconds.  I'm testing this on a Samsung running OREO.

The AudioFeedbackListener seems to be backwards to the Android SDK's perspective, as Android recommends asking for focus, waiting for a grant, and then proceed with the audio.  However, that isn't an option in HERE (without taking over the Audio entirely with an Audio Delegate, at least I haven't seen any APIs that will work like that.

I see that in the HERE maps IOS SDK there is a parameter for [`audioRouteLatencyCompensation`](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics/audio-management.html) that is mentioned to help with ducking, but that isn't available for Android.

Below is a snippet of my audio listener that that handles the audio focus, and in my logs all the calls return GRANTED.

Has anyone else encountered this, or have suggestions of how to delay the HERE voice prompts and beeps until the focus has been granted?

```
private NavigationManager.AudioFeedbackListener mAudioListener = new NavigationManager.AudioFeedbackListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioStart() {
        super.onAudioStart();
        Log.d(TAG,"audio feedback listener: onAudioStart");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mFocusRequest);
            Log.d(TAG,"Android_O request audio focus result=" + result);
        } else {
            int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                    m_navigationManager.getAudioPlayer().getStreamId(),
                    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
            Log.d(TAG,"request audio focus result=" + result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioEnd() {
        super.onAudioEnd();
        Log.d(TAG,"audio feedback listener: onAudioEnd");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int result = mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocusRequest(mFocusRequest);
            Log.d(TAG,"Android_O abandonAudioFocusRequest result=" + result);
        } else {
            mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Here SDK there is no way provided yet to get AudioFeedbackListener calls before the audio playing starts. The AudioFeedbackListener calls are pushed into the main application loop and them they are called asynchronously after existing events.
But playing of audio starts immediately. As result your application receives audio events after the audio playing starts. The delay you see depends on current user activity, device processor load and etc.